# Is it possible to satisfy both Jack and Serenity at the same time?

Tags: scribblenauts-unlimited

In the **Metaforest** stage of Scribblenauts Unlimited you find Jack the woodcutter and Serenity the treehugger facing off each other.

[image]

They'll each give you a starlite piece, but only, it seems, if you foil the other's plan - Serenity wants you to stop Jack, while Jack wants to cut down the tree. Obviously you can fulfill one, reset, then get the other, but is there any way of giving both of them what they want at the same time?

Comment: Have you tried stopping Jack first, then cutting the tree down yourself? If setting Jack asleep is enough for Serenity to grant her starite, you can then remove the adjective and let Jack do his things afterwards.

Comment: I have got an Idea, but i´m not sure it is possible...
Make the Tree immortal, Then give Jack his Weapon, then help Serenity.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to satisfy both Jack and Serenity at the same time. Completing one mission will cancel the other person's mission, as indicated by them no longer glowing when using Starite Vision. You will need to reset if you want to complete both missions.

I attempted the following:

- Making the tree immortal (Satisfies Serenity) then giving Jack an axe

  - When Jack's mission hadn't been completed, Jack didn't react
  - When Jack's mission had been completed and then reset, Jack attempted to cut down the immortal tree.
- Making Jack sleepy (Satisfied Serenity) then waking him up (Jack ran away when woken up)
- Giving Jack an axe (Satisfies Jack) then making a new Redwood tree
- Giving Jack an axe then adding the adjective "Fixed" to the tree
- Giving Jack an Axe then making the tree immortal before Jack could cut it down

  - Serenity ran away and Jack tried to cut down the tree. Jack's mission was not satisfied.